# Стек потока и стек процесса?

Tags: архитектура, процесс, процессор, виртуальная-память, эвм

Процесс имеет код программы, данные, стек, куча. У каждого процесса есть поток, это то что указывает какую команду выполнять из стека процессора? А когда несколько потоков то у каждого потока создаётся свой стек из которого выбирается какая команда выполняться должна?

Answer (score 1):

Вы ошибаетесь. Выполняемые команды не хранятся на стеке, они хранятся по указателю IP (instruction pointer).

Поток - это абстрактный термин, описывающий контекст выполнения программы в многопоточной среде. С потоком связывают набор регистров процессора, в том числе, stack pointer и instruction pointer, TLS и некоторые другие сущности, зависящие от операционной системы, рантайма и применяемого языка программирования.

Так что да, поток указывает, какую инструкцию выполнять, но это только малая часть от его контекста.

Comment: а когда несколько потоков, у каждого потока свой указатель на выполняемую инструкцию? И стек общий откуда они берут команды(указывают какую выполнять)?

Comment: Еще раз внимательно прочитайте мое сообщение. У каждого потока СВОЙ стек и СВОЙ указатель инструкций.

*Инструкции на стеке не хранятся*